# How to import your own java class inside a .js file with node-java module?

Tags: java, node.js

I installed the node-java module
(https://github.com/joeferner/node-java).

I have two files under the same folder named 'Code', one is test.js which has the following code:

```
let java= require('java');

let mySumTest= java.import('MySumClass');
console.log(mySumTest.sum(2, 5));
```

The other file is MySumClass.java:

```
public class MySumClass{
    public static int sum(int a, int b){
        return a+b;
    }
}
```

But when I try to run the test.js file (./Code> node test.js), the node.js command prompt says that:

```
Error: Could not create class MySumClass
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: MySumClass
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MySumClass
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

It is possible that I misunderstood how to use the import function of the node-java module. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By default, `node-java` will only have the objects from the default Java runtime library available. The classes you defined yourself (like `MySumClass`) will need to be compiled and added to your classpath before you can import and use them.

Make sure you compile your `MySumClass.java` file (using `javac` for example). For adding the compiled file to the classpath used by `node-java`, you can use [java.classpath](https://github.com/joeferner/node-java#javaClasspath).

```js
java.classpath.push('MySumClass.class');
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will try your solution when I get home

Comment: Hello! Sorry for getting so long to get back to you, I took a sick break.

Even when I pushed the MySumClass.class as you suggested, the sum method can still not be found.

I looked here and there about the classpath and tried alot of things, until finally I just had to make a jar file out of the MySumClass.class and push it to classpath to work.

Still, thank you for leading me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of trying, this is what worked for me:
(test.jar is in same directory as the other files)

```
let java= require('java');
java.classpath.push('test.jar');

let mySumTest= java.import("MySumClass");

/*
//this prints out undefined, don't know why
console.log(java.callStaticMethod("MySumClass", "sum", 2, 5, function(err, results){
    if(err){
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }
    else return results;
}));
*/

var result= java.callStaticMethodSync("MySumClass", "sum", 2, 5)
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

What I did was basically follow the OP's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58466442/12096922), but I had beforehand to create the `.jar` file. To do so, I just prepared my custom class in `test.java`:

```
import java.lang.System;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, world!");
    }
}
```

And then

```
javac Test.java
jar cf test.jar Test.class
```

Now you should see the `.jar` created. From this point, you are able to access it from Javascript:

```js
let java= require('java');
java.classpath.push('test.jar');

let test = java.import("Test");
test.main(null) // should print "Hello, World!"
```